# How can I make proper sandwich slices of home-made bread?

Tags: bread

I like baking my own bread and do it quite often, yet to fill our family lunch boxes we still resort to professional baked bread. The main and maybe the only reason is that we can't seem to slice our own baked bread as thin as you like to fit in a lunchbox. 
We could of course buy an electric bread slicer similar as the one you'll find in your local supermarket, but that is quite some overkill.

[image: Bread slicer]

[source](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:St._Louis_electrical_bread_slicer,_1930.png)

I have tried it many times, even with very sharp knives, but I never managed to get a slices smaller then 1 cm in thickness. 
Is there some technique or device that enables proper slices of home-made bread?

Comment: What defines a proper sandwich? If it's sticky stuff (jam, marmite etc.) to smear on the bread, just put it on a fat hand made slice, and fold in half. If "filling", put it in a reusable zipper bag, and pour onto one fat hand made slice before eating

Comment: @TFD Sure, it's a personal preference, but the OP seems to have fairly clearly specified what they're looking for: thin (<1cm), even slices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy a [home bread slicer](http://www.norpro.com/store/products/bread-slicer-wcrumb-catcher) - and you can also [make one.](http://www.motherearthnews.com/diy/diy-bread-slicer-zmaz78mazjma.aspx#axzz30BvHV5Y4)

> "My little invention works on the same principle as a carpenter's miter
>   box (as a matter of fact, I got the idea while watching a carpenter
>   friend cut some miter joints). The only difference is that my device
>   was made specifically for slicing homemade bread. Just slide a loaf
>   into place, position the blade of a long, sharp knife in the slots,
>   and you can't help but cut straight and true." *- John Shell, Mother Earth News March/April 1978*

Comment: It has slots every 1/2 inch ... so they'd be 1.28cm/slice.

Comment: Got the drvice through amazon, it works, great answer

Answer (score 2):

I find that a rediculously sharp serrated blade is the key -- I have a Wüstof bread knife with what they call a 'wavy edge' -- it looks more like a [scalloped edge](http://www.wuesthof.com/usa/products/product-details/super-slicer-4532).  I find it goes through bread much cleaner than a standard serrated knife.  (if it has a soft crumb, it don't end up with the surface of the cut looking chewed up).

You also want a knife that's fairly long -- you want to take nice, long strokes with very little downward pressure; if you can, just blade slowly fall through the bread as you push it back and forth.  Short strokes will end up with more of the 'chewed up' look.

I also find that the type of bread, and how you store it can be significant -- if the crust is too hard (eg, non-enriched breads), I find it more difficult to make a sandwich from it.  I keep loaves that I know I'm going to be slicing thinly in a plastic bag, so the crust doesn't overly dry out (eg home-baked or those from the farmer's market they sell in paper bags or perforated plastic bags, I throw 'em in a plastic grocery bag when I get home, so it doesn't dry out in 24-48 hrs).  If you have a bread box, that would work, too.

... and if none of those tips help, there are [knives with 'slicing guides'](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001BTO708) available in a [range of prices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004TTJI7E) that have a parallel bar to help give you a reference so you'll slice more uniformly.  To use them, you need a slightly different technique; as the guide protrudes past the blade, you need to make the last pass with only the tip of the blade.

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me:  [http://www.amazon.com/EdgeCraft-610-Choice-Premium-Electric/dp/B0002AKCOC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002AKCOC)
and I can slice meat and cheese too!

Answer (score 0):

You may find that an electric knife (not a full electric slicer) makes it much easier to slice bread thinly, as the back and forth action saws through cleanly and you don't have the tearing or pulling that may happen with a regular knife if it is not perfectly sharp or used with perfect technique.

If find that using mine makes it easy to make small croutons every year for thanksgiving stuffing.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't really work well with crusty bread.

Comment: I am quite surprised; usually they are quite good at that.

Answer (score 0):

My wife suggested using our electric meat slicer. I did and it worked great.

Comment: this is an inadequate answer because, it does not help facilitate the curvature of the cut itself (keep the slice straight).  It only helps with the actual slicing of the bread, which doesn't guarantee width of each slice or continual identical results.  If you disagree, you need to state this in you answer.

Comment: Actually, it does if the blade is sharp, IME.